# Daemontools shell script log to multilog

Tags: python, shell

I have the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
echo "Starting ..."
python /home/services/example.py
```

The python script consists just of a print command. The above script is a daemontools daemon and also a simple log mechanism is enabled (`multilog`). However, in the `main/log/current` I see the line "Starting ..." but not the printed commands from the python script.

Am I doing something wrong with the call or did I forget something?

**EDIT**
The python script I am trying to run is:

```
from time import sleep
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Hello World")
print "Hello World"

while 1:
    sys.stdout.write("Hello world")
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: If you write a Python script that, say, writes to `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` every 10 seconds, does it reproduce the problem? If not, you might have something more interesting -- like a script that checks whether stderr is a tty before deciding whether to log to it. This would require looking into the specifics of the program run to reproduce or solve, if so.

Comment: [...as another aside, not really essential to the issue at hand, you'd be well-advised to make it `exec python /home/services/example.py` -- that way any signals will go straight to the Python service, not to the shell that's running it].

Comment: (Another possibility is that output isn't being line-buffered or otherwise flushed, but that would be a bit surprising if true; still depends on the details of the program being run, so results of an attempt to build a minimal reproducer would be helpful).

Comment: I added the python script and removed the not need `2>&1`

Comment: Thank you -- those details are sufficient to make this answerable. (If you'd just put `print "Hello World"` inside the loop's body, that would have worked; the switch to `sys.stdout` creates a need for more care).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatedly running

```
sys.stdout.write("Hello world")
```

...just creates a single huge line of the form `Hello worldHello worldHello world`, with no guarantee that it ever flushes.

Put newlines on any content you write that doesn't have them implicitly (as through `print`), and flush your buffers when directly using `sys.stdout.write()`:

```
while 1:
    sys.stdout.write("Hello world\n")  # add a newline
    sys.stdout.flush()                 # flush the buffer
```

Comment: Thank you so far. I also observed something interesting. Only with the linebreak `\n` at the end, it really adds it immediately to the stdout. Otherwise it is only added, when I send the `-d` signal since it is one line.

Comment: That means you're configured for line buffering. Not particularly surprising as a default.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue too.

The solution is to disable output buffering. See [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)

In your case, update your daemontools run script to:

```
python -u /home/services/example.py
```

The -u flag disables Python output buffering.